# Нужно найти в таблице все колонки типа decimal и поменять тип на float

Tags: sql, sql-server

Помогите, пожалуйста, сделать скрипт на SQL, который ищет в таблице все колонки типа decimal и меняет их тип на float
субд - Ms sql

Comment: укажите конкретную СУБД

Comment: здравсвуйте, указал)

Comment: напишите запрос к схеме данных. выберите все столбцы. сформируйте в текстовом виде запрос. и выполните его.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пример скрипта. Задайте имя своей таблицы в переменной @TableName.

```
DECLARE @TableName nvarchar(256) = N'dbo.TableName'
       ,@cmd       nvarchar(MAX)

SELECT @cmd = (SELECT N'ALTER TABLE ' + @TableName + N' ALTER COLUMN [' + name + N'] float; '
                 FROM sys.columns
                WHERE object_id = object_id(@TableName) AND system_type_id = 106
                FOR XML PATH(''))
EXECUTE (@cmd)
```

P.S. Посмотреть идентификаторы типов можно в представлении sys.types